# Where was the rest of the crew in Interstellar?

Tags: interstellar

In the movie *Interstellar* they left Earth to another galaxy. Five people left for the mission. When they arrive, part of the crew explores the planet with waves.

> One of three people dies at the planet. Romilly (portrayed by David Gyasi) then welcomes them back on the Endeavor, after 23 years which he was living on the ship and not in the cryosleep.

Where is the last member of the crew, Doyle (portrayed by Wes Bentley)?

Comment: FTR, he did say that he twice went into cryosleep.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interstellar_(film)#Plot

Answer (score 13):

There are only four in the crew of the Endurance: Cooper, Brand, Doyle and Rommily.

> Doyle is the one killed on the water world.

Answer (score 2):

There were only *four* human crew members aboard the Endurance;

- Amelia Brand
- NFN Doyle
- NFN Romilly
- Joseph "Coop" Cooper

And two robots

- TARS
- CASE.

> *Flipping switches and adjusting settings,  **Amelia, Doyle, and Romilly
> began powering up what would be their home for — well, who knew how
> long?She watched Tars activate Case, an articulated machine like
> himself, who made up the final member of their crew.***
>
> <sub><sup>[Interstellar - Official Novelisation](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/21488063-interstellar) (Plus all quotes below)</sup></sub>

---

**Doyle died on Miller's World**

> *The Ranger tilted sharply and seawater slapped Doyle back, out of
> Case’s grip, as it came raging across the hatch. The ship was lifted
> and everything went sideways. **That fast—the blink of an eye—Doyle was
> gone.***

**Romilly died on Mann's World**

> *There was nothing to be seen of Mann’s pod but billowing, oily black
> smoke, and **Cooper knew Romilly was dead.** Mann’s story about Kipp had
> been pure bullshit—Kipp had collected data proving the planet was
> uninhabitable, and Mann had shut him down. He must have also
> booby-trapped him, in case anyone started prying.*

**TARS and Cooper survived and transited to Cooper Station.**

> *He also recognized the voice. **Tars. “You survived,” Cooper said.***

**Amelia Brand and CASE survived and traveled to Edmund's World**

> *Amelia watched, weeping, as Case excavated Wolf’s pod, buried beneath
> a massive rock fall. **Only the robot and the desert witnessed her
> grief.***